# Simple products are not showing on magento site: Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, simple-product, not-found

I have recently created the new Product category and a simple product in it and shows it on front end using block but it giving this error "There are no products matching the selection." as the product is present there still it giving me error:

I have tried by clearing the cache and login and logout again but still the same issue.

Any Help in this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Add your code here

Comment: Make sure you give permissions to that block in ADMIN >> SYSTEM >> PERMISSIONS >> BLOCK

Comment: are you using a static block assignment to the category from admin or using some code to display in the frontend. please mention how you are trying to display product to frontend.

Comment: also check 'visibility' and 'inventory' options

Comment: @Ashish Madankar  I have created a new template for the products and get them as like this:
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list')->setCategoryId(78)->setTemplate('catalog/product/sample.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>

Comment: @Xabby thanks for the update, first confirm whether this phtml is calling or not by simply adding a static data like <h1>Calling Custom template.</h1> if its calling then check for inventory, Stock Availability, website name, visibility and status.

Comment: But it is already showing some products that i have added earlier but not showing the new ones that i ve added now @Ashish Madankar

Answer (score 1):

I think its visibility is hideen
Go to magento admin panel menu

Catalog => Product => Select product and got to product information There is drop-down Here select one of these option

Comment: That's all ok i have checked it

Comment: i am using a template and get all the products as like this:
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list')->setCategoryId(78)->setTemplate('catalog/product/sample.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>

Comment: There is a re-index process is remaining is that the issue?

Comment: make sure product status is enable and there is quantity.                  $category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category ();
$category->load ( $catid );
$prodCollection = $category->getProductCollection ();